# How to I cache a particular View on client side.- ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set the contents of a Login View i my ASP.NET MVC 3 application so that it won't eat the bandwidth again if I refresh the login page because every time it would be same. So, I want the Login View contents (mostly images) to be available for 10 minutes once rendered. How can I do this? please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decorate the controller action that is rendering your `LogOn` view with the [`[OutputCache]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Sorry if ask for your help here, but I really need a hand here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403503/jquery-how-to-split-table-cell-into-a-different-number-of-rows-from-column-to-co Again, I do apologize for commenting on someone else's question